# Cassandra streaming failed

Tags: cassandra

I am having some problem with cassandra 2.0.8 that after I have restarted it, it cannot join the cluster with the "stream failed" exception, then it stops running. Until that time, node stays in JOINING state.

Do you have any idea why stream fails in cassandra?

Logs:

```
ERROR [main] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,063 CassandraDaemon.java (line 513) Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during boostrap: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:86)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1035)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:797)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:614)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:504)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:378)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:496)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:585)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:85)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1160)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:216)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:191)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:348)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.convict(StreamSession.java:617)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.FailureDetector.interpret(FailureDetector.java:237)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doStatusCheck(Gossiper.java:643)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.access$700(Gossiper.java:64)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper$GossipTask.run(Gossiper.java:170)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,063 StatusLogger.java (line 70) GossipStage                       0         0            537         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,081 StatusLogger.java (line 70) CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,082 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MigrationStage                    0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,083 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MemoryMeter                       1         1             28         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,084 StatusLogger.java (line 70) ValidationExecutor                0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,085 StatusLogger.java (line 70) FlushWriter                       0         0             20         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,086 StatusLogger.java (line 70) InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,087 StatusLogger.java (line 70) AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,087 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MemtablePostFlusher               0         0             49         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,088 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,095 StatusLogger.java (line 70) PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              3         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,098 StatusLogger.java (line 70) commitlog_archiver                0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,099 StatusLogger.java (line 70) CompactionExecutor               10        10            142         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,100 StatusLogger.java (line 70) HintedHandoff                     0         0              2         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,104 StatusLogger.java (line 79) CompactionManager                10        19
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,105 StatusLogger.java (line 81) Commitlog                       n/a         2
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,106 StatusLogger.java (line 93) MessagingService                n/a    0/1217
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,107 StatusLogger.java (line 103) Cache Type                     Size                 Capacity               KeysToSave
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,107 StatusLogger.java (line 105) KeyCache                     373840               3221225472                      all
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,108 StatusLogger.java (line 111) RowCache                          0               3221225472                      all
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,108 StatusLogger.java (line 118) ColumnFamily                Memtable ops,data
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,109 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.schema_triggers                    0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,109 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.local                              0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,109 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.peers                              0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,110 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.batchlog                           0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,110 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.NodeIdInfo                         0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,110 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.compactions_in_progress                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,111 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.schema_keyspaces                   0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,111 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.compaction_history             20,6271
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,112 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.paxos                              0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,112 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.schema_columns                     0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,112 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.schema_columnfamilies                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,113 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.IndexInfo                          0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,113 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.range_xfers                        0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,113 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.peer_events                        0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,114 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.hints                              0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,114 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.sstable_activity                   0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,115 StatusLogger.java (line 121) monitor.metric_data_30min                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,115 StatusLogger.java (line 121) monitor.metric_data_24hour                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,115 StatusLogger.java (line 121) monitor.metric_data_2hour                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,116 StatusLogger.java (line 121) monitor.metric_test                       0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,116 StatusLogger.java (line 121) monitor.time_data_5min         82442,15530317
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,116 StatusLogger.java (line 121) monitor.time_data_30min                   0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,117 StatusLogger.java (line 121) monitor.metric_data_5min      155046,91535821
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,117 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system_traces.sessions                    0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,118 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system_traces.events                      0,0
 INFO [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,167 Gossiper.java (line 1271) Announcing shutdown
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:17] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,194 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:18] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,196 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:19] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,199 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:20] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,205 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:21] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,215 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:22] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,219 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:23] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,224 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:24] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,238 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:25] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,244 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:26] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,249 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:28] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,258 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:27] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,258 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:29] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,263 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:30] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,268 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:31] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,275 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:32] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,283 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [RequestResponseStage:17] 2015-01-17 17:52:10,283 Gossiper.java (line 869) InetAddress /x.y.z.t is now UP
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-17 17:52:12,125 GCInspector.java (line 116) GC for ParNew: 459 ms for 1 collections, 7433903048 used; max is 12759072768
 INFO [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2015-01-17 17:52:12,170 MessagingService.java (line 683) Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
 INFO [ACCEPT-cassandra/x.y.z.t] 2015-01-17 17:52:12,175 MessagingService.java (line 923) MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a little aggressive in 2.0.8 on timeouts for convict. So if the networks a little flakey it can fail like this. There was an update in 2.0.9 that helps: [CASSANDRA-7063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7063).

Can work around it possibly by increasing phi_convict in your cassandra.yaml temporarily.

Comment: Yep, I had the same problem a while back.  DataStax's support also advised me to increase my `phi_convict_threshold`, which worked.